# Event Hub Consumer in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to get a service fabric to consistently pull messages from an azure event hub. I seem to have everything wired up but notice that my consumer just stops pulling events.

I have a hub with a couple thousand events I've pushed to it. Configured the hub with 1 partition and have my service fabric service with also only 1 partition to ease debugging.

Service starts, creates the EventHubClient, from there uses it to create a PartitionReceiver. The receiver is passed to an "EventLoop" that enters an "infinite" while that calls receiver.ReceiveAsync. The code for the EventLoop is below.

What I am observing is the first time through the loop I almost always get 1 message. Second time through I get somewhere between 103 and 200ish messages. After that, I get no messages. Also seems like if I restart the service, I get the same messages again - but that's because when I restart the service I'm having it start back at the beginning of the stream.

Would expect this to keep running until my 2000 messages were consumed and then it would wait for me (polling ocassionally).

Is there something specific I need to do with the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.3.0 package to make it keep pulling events?

```
//Here is how I am creating the EventHubClient:
var connectionString = "something secret";
var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
{
   EntityPath = "NameOfMyEventHub"
};
try
{
   m_eventHubClient = EventHubClient.Create(connectionStringBuilder);
}

//Here is how I am getting the partition receiver
var receiver = m_eventHubClient.CreateReceiver("$Default", m_partitionId, EventPosition.FromStart());

//The event loop which the receiver is passed to
private async Task EventLoop(PartitionReceiver receiver)
  {
     m_started = true;
     while (m_keepRunning)
     {
        var events = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(m_options.BatchSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        if (events != null) //First 2/3 times events aren't null. After that, always null and I know there are more in the partition/
        {
           var eventsArray = events as EventData[] ?? events.ToArray();
           m_state.NumProcessedSinceLastSave += eventsArray.Count();

           foreach (var evt in eventsArray)
           {
              //Process the event
              await m_options.Processor.ProcessMessageAsync(evt, null);

              string lastOffset = evt.SystemProperties.Offset;

              if (m_state.NumProcessedSinceLastSave >= m_options.BatchSize)
              {
                 m_state.Offset = lastOffset;
                 m_state.NumProcessedSinceLastSave = 0;
                 await m_state.SaveAsync();
              }
           }
        }
     }

     m_started = false;
  }
```

**EDIT, a question was asked on the number of partitions. The event hub has a single partition and the SF service also has a single one.

Intending to use service fabric state to keep track of my offset into the hub, but that's not the concern for now.

Partition listeners are created for each partition. I get the partitions like this:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
  {
     // slice the pie according to distribution
     // this partition can get one or more assigned Event Hub Partition ids
     string[] eventHubPartitionIds = (await m_eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformationAsync()).PartitionIds;
     string[] resolvedEventHubPartitionIds = m_options.ResolveAssignedEventHubPartitions(eventHubPartitionIds);

     foreach (var resolvedPartition in resolvedEventHubPartitionIds)
     {
        var partitionReceiver = new EventHubListenerPartitionReceiver(m_eventHubClient, resolvedPartition, m_options);
        await partitionReceiver.StartAsync();
        m_partitionReceivers.Add(partitionReceiver);
     }
  }
```

When the partitionListener.StartAsync is called, it actually creates the PartitionListener, like this (it's actually a bit more than this, but the branch taken is this one:

```
m_eventHubClient.CreateReceiver(m_options.EventHubConsumerGroupName, m_partitionId, EventPosition.FromStart());
```

Thanks for any tips.
Will

Comment: Can you help me understand how `m_keepRunning` is governed?   I see it being used as part of the loop control, but it would be helpful to see how its value is managed by the application.

Comment: It is set to false on the CloseAsync when service fabric shuts the service down.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the code that was shared.   I wonder if there's an unobserved exception that is causing the task to crash.   The loop has no error handling in the version that was shared.  What's the exception handling strategy in `ProcessMessageAsync`?

Comment: >> _Is there something specific I need to do with the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.3.0 package to make it keep pulling events?_    I'm not sure what you're asking there.  The snippets that you've shared are using the legacy `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` package, not the current generation `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`.

Comment: @JesseSquire that is an interesting observation. The package referenced is Azure.Messaging.EventHubs (5.3.0-beta.4) but you are indeed correct, when I go to definition on the EventHubClient, it is in // C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.eventhubs\4.3.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.dll, even though that package is not even referenced in my project. No doubt it once was. Let me unravel that and maybe the issue will sort itself out.

Comment: Can you use Service Bus Explorer and compare the results? I wonder if some of the messages are already out of retention period and not delivered because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many partition do you have? I can't see in your code how you make sure you read all partitions in the default consumer group.

Any specific reason why you are using `PartitionReceiver`  instead of using an [EventProcessorHost](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor)?

To me, SF seems like a perfect fit for using the event processor host. I see there is already a [SF integrated solution](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/ServiceFabricProcessor/ProgrammersGuide.md) that uses stateful services for checkpointing.

Comment: To answer the partition question, the event hub has 1 partition and the SF service also has only one - was thinking that could also be the culprit so I ruled it out. I'll add some of those details to my main post.

Comment: The mentioned &linked SF integration package uses a stateful service instead of storage account .

Comment: Just to make mention, the link above reommended to use the current generation library, `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.`  The `EventProcessorHost` link in the answer points to the correct library but the name of the type would be `EventProcessorClient` in that package.  For this scenario, deriving from [`EventProcesor<T>`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Primitives/EventProcessor.cs) would be the better approach, to allow for using Service Fabric state as checkpoint storage.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm investigating these recommendations. Should sort it out.

Comment: @JesseSquire I see you contributing on the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs project. In the doc there, it says, "For production use, we recommend using the Event Processor Client". That links to the project for Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor. Does anyone have a sample showing the use of EventProcessor<T> within Service Fabric? Side note: Why are there even so many libraries for this stuff and how is the public expected to know which to use without coming to stack overflow?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a good sample available yet for customizing `EventProcessor<T>`... the best example at this point is the [`EventProcessorClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor/src/EventProcessorClient.cs) which is an opinionated customization on top of it.

Comment: We would recommend using the `Azure.[[ AREA ]].[[ SERVICE ]]` family of packages for new development or non-trivial updates. 

With respect to the motivations and differences, as Azure has matured and been embraced by a more diverse group of developers, we have been focused on learning the patterns and practices to best support developer productivity and to understand the gaps that the .NET client libraries have.

Comment: There were several areas of consistent feedback expressed across the Azure client library ecosystem.  One of the most important is that the client libraries for different Azure services have not had a consistent approach to organization, naming, and API structure.  Additionally, many developers have felt that the learning curve was difficult, and the APIs did not offer a good, approachable, and consistent onboarding story for those learning Azure or exploring a specific Azure service.

Comment: To try and improve the development experience across Azure services, a set of uniform [design guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/general_introduction.html) was created for all languages to drive a consistent experience with established API patterns for all services.  A set of [.NET-specific guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html) was also introduced to ensure that .NET clients have a natural and idiomatic feel that mirrors that of the .NET base class libraries.  Further context, rationale, and details are available in the linked guidelines.

Comment: Thanks everyone. After going through that exercise of ensuring the right packages were used, I ended up finding the issue. Turns out it was in my silly unit test that wasn't awaiting. The test was ending and killing the task before all the messages were on the hub - and it was consistently ending after the exact same amount just by chance...
Glad to be on the new packages though so your help improved things overall for me.